# Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration in Cypress

Tags: node.js, webpack, cypress

Guys cypress is displaying the error message below. I believe the error occurred because of some plugin I installed but I can't say which one. Can anyone help?

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/support/commands.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cypress' in 'C:\Dev\Projeto_Alper_Caixa\cypress\support'
resolve 'cypress' in 'C:\Dev\Projeto_Alper_Caixa\cypress\support'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Dev\Projeto_Alper_Caixa\package.json (relative path: ./cypress/support)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    Looked for and couldn't find the file at the following paths:
[C:\Dev\Projeto_Alper_Caixa\cypress\support\node_modules]
[C:\Dev\Projeto_Alper_Caixa\cypress\node_modules]
[C:\Dev\node_modules]
[C:\node_modules]
[C:\Dev\Projeto_Alper_Caixa\node_modules\cypress]
[C:\Dev\Projeto_Alper_Caixa\node_modules\cypress.js]
[C:\Dev\Projeto_Alper_Caixa\node_modules\cypress.json]
[C:\Dev\Projeto_Alper_Caixa\node_modules\cypress.jsx]
[C:\Dev\Projeto_Alper_Caixa\node_modules\cypress.mjs]
[C:\Dev\Projeto_Alper_Caixa\node_modules\cypress.coffee]
 @ ./cypress/support/commands.js 5:38-56
 @ ./cypress/support/index.js
 
    at Watching.handle [as handler] (C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-preprocessor\dist\index.js:180:23)
    at C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:99:9
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Watching._done (C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:98:28)
    at C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:73:19
    at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:499:39)
    at C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:54:20
    at C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:485:14
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:482:27
    at C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2818:7
    at done (C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3522:9)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:464:33
    at C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:111:16
    at C:\Users\losp\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:61:14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so during the troubleshoot our goal would be to reach the nearest version of node required as we can see in below error logs.

```
-bash-3.2$ npm update
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: undefined,
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '14.17.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v17.2.0', npm: '8.1.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
added 7 packages, removed 6 packages, changed 57 packages, and audited 350 packages in 11s
64 packages are looking for funding
run npm fund for details
added 7 packages, removed 6 packages, changed 57 packages, and audited 350 packages in 11s
64 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

As we currently have 17.2.0 and the required is 14.17.0.
To fix this

```
npm cache clear
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g cypress
sudo n 14.17.0
rm -rf **put your existing version**.
```

{Perform the above in the folder where your previous version of node was installed}

Open a new terminal

```
node -v 
npm install
npx cypress open
```

**This works for mac, not tried in windows/ubuntu**